# In c# what does mean "< ? :"?

Tags: c#, return-value

In c# what does mean < ? : in this string?

```
return (a < b ? c: "text") + " ";
```

Comment: For the benefit of SO users: what C# programming book do you use?  They'll want to know what to avoid.

Comment: Lol at the million near-identical answers posted already!

Comment: 15 answers in three minutes?! New record?

Comment: I feel like I should attempt an answer...

Comment: @Mark, and about half gave it the wrong name!

Comment: The downvotes are a little harsh, I remember about 6 months ago another developer was looking through a coding standards document and pointed out a ternary operator to me and asked what it was, I had never seen one either so I would assume they either arent commonly used, or not commonly used in some areas.

Comment: i agree. it's not the worst question i've ever seen, far from it.

Comment: Down votes are ridiculous so are some of the comments, this is a question answer website for all levels of programmers or technically gifted people. If you down vote atleast advise why so user can improve or be a bit more helpful not everyones at the same level and you got to account for that.

Comment: @Anicho: Exactly. `An ignorant person is one who doesn't know what you have just found out.` - Will Rogers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It is a ternary operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
condition ? truePart : falsePart
```

It means if `a` is less then `b` then return `c` else return `"text"`. Both values will have `" "` appended before returning...

Oh, but please don't use the variable names `a`, `b` and `c` in your own code :)

Comment: No, it is **a** ternary operator. It's the Conditional Operator, which is an example of a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

The `? :` is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). If the first argument is true, it evaluates and returns the second argument, otherwise it evaluates and returns the third argument.

Your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
if (a < b)
{
    return c + " ";
}
else
{
    return "text" + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a is being compared with b and is evaluated as a boolean,

So if a < b is true then c is returned

in case it evaluates to false then text is returned.

In either case you have a single space returned additionally in the end

Read more on [Conditional Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and also [Relational Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5wecxwa%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if `a` is less than(<) `b` then(?) `return c` otherwise(:) `return "text"`

Basically there is no `< ? :` operator, you're seeing two separate operators, '`<`' and the '`?:`' operator, which is ternary and therefore takes three inputs (in this order):

1) An expression that is a boolean (in this case the `<` comparison)

2) What to return when 1) is true

3) What to return when 1) is false

Comment: Think you've misread slightly :)

Comment: yeah - not `" "` but `"text"` - god these flying SO visits are dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

that means that if `a` is less than `b` then return `c`, otherwise return `"text"` and then add `" "` to the end in both cases.

MSDN doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

it is a ternary operator which basically is a short form of "if-then-else"... the above would be:

```
if (a < b)
{
   return c + " ";
}
else
{
   return "text ";
}
```

For reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: The single-space string is being tagged onto both conditions.

Comment: yes - if you look exactly then you see that I included the space in the second return (no need to "add" two literals!).

Answer (score 1):

It's the conditional operator.

Same as this:

```
if (a < b)
   return "c" + " ";
else 
   return "text" + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a short way of writing if else condition

```
if a is less then b
    then return c + " ";
otherwise 
    return "text" + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a if statement, using tenary operator. You can read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

In your case `condition` is `a < b` and so this translates to

```
string retVal;
if (a < b)
{
    retVal = c;
}
else
{
    retVal = "text";
}

return retVal + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called a ternary operator<sup>[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)</sup>. It is short for

```
var str = "";
if( a < b)
  str = c;
else
  str = "text"
str += " ";
return str;
```

Comment: that is entirely possible without the extra variable...

Comment: @Yahia - of course it is, the variable was to illustrate what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is **a** Ternary operation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation ).  Basically, the expression on the left is evaluated.  If it evaluates to true, the result is the expression to the left of the `:`.  If it is false, it is the one after.

In your example, if a is less than b, the result is c, otherwise `text`.

Comment: No, it is **a** ternary operator. It's the Conditional Operator, which is an example of a ternary operator.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett , edited for clarity, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice George is really enforcing this concept!

Answer (score 1):

The < operator checks if the left operand is smaller than the right operand.

The ? (Also called the ternary operator) yields, in this case, *c* if *a < b* and *text* otherwise.

Comment: No, it is **a** ternary operator. It's the Conditional Operator, which is an example of a ternary operator.

Comment: Yeah but people commonly (And mistakenly) call it *the* ternary operator. Sorry for spreading the misinformation.

Comment: Given people often call it that by mistake, i'd note in the answer that it's a mistake to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a is greater than b return c + " " else return "text" + " "
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a conditional operator, which is a type of ternary operator - as it takes 3 variables.
It is equivalent to

```
if(a < b)
{ 
   return c + " ";
}
else 
{
   return "text" + " ";
}
```

Comment: It's the Conditional Operator, which is an example of a ternary operator.